# I have a delegate method that never gets called......Why?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

This is the delegate method that doesn't get called. I tried everything but it never gets called for some reason. Im trying to make a multiplayer game using game center in Swift. I have a function in my MultiplayerNetworking.swift file that I have to call in the delegate function in the GameScene.swift. Can someone help me? Thanks!

```
//GameScene.swift

/* For protocol GKMatchDelegate */

func match(match: GKMatch, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromRemotePlayer playerID: GKPlayer) {
    println("calllittttttt")
    if _match != match {
        return


    }


    MultiplayerNetworking().match(match, didReceiveData: data, fromRemotPlayer: playerID)

}


//MultiplayerNetworking.Swift

   func match(match:GKMatch, didReceiveData data: NSData!, fromRemotPlayer playerID: GKPlayer) {




    let message = UnsafePointer<Message>(data.bytes).memory

    if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeRandomNumber) {
        let messageRandomNumber = UnsafePointer<MessageRandomNumber>(data.bytes).memory

        println("Received random number: \(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)")

        var tie = false

        if(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber == _ourRandomNumber) {
            println("Tie")
            tie = true
            _ourRandomNumber = arc4random()
            self.sendRandomNumber()
        }
        else {
            var dictionary = ["\(playerIDKey)":"\(playerID)", "\(randomNumberKey)":"\(messageRandomNumber.randomNumber)"]
            self.processReceivedRandomNumber(dictionary)
        }

        if(_receivedAllRandomNumbers) {
            _isPlayer1 = self.isLocalPlayerPlayer1()
        }

        if(!tie && _receivedAllRandomNumbers) {
            if(_gameState == GameState.kGameStateWaitingForRandomNumber) {
                _gameState = GameState.kGameStateWaitingForStart
            }
            self.tryStartGame()
        }
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameBegin) {
        println("Begin game message received")
        _gameState = GameState.kGameStateActive
        self.delegate?.setCurrentPlayerIndex(self.indexForLocalPlayer())
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeMove) {
        println("Move message received")
        let messageMove = UnsafePointer<MessageMove>(data.bytes).memory
        self.delegate?.movePlayerAtIndex(indexForPlayerWithId(playerIDKey))
    }
    else if(message.messageType == MessageType.kMessageTypeGameOver) {
        println("Game over message received")
        let messageGameOver = UnsafePointer<MessageGameOver>(data.bytes).memory
        self.delegate?.gameOver(messageGameOver.player1Won)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever assign the delegate like instance.delegate = desiredClassToReceiveDelegateMethods?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa I didn't with the other delegate methods and they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your delegate will be nil. po your delegate and see.

Comment: print object i guess ... when you write po object in the console. xcode will print the object's description.

Comment: ohh I did that it doesn't print anything.

Comment: it will happen at the time of debugging. you need to put the break point at the line where your delegate method being called. and write this line on console. Console will be available in the bottom of the xcode like this http://tinypic.com/r/adf628/8

Comment: that means you haven't set the delegate. I think you should spare some time and read how delegate patterns works......

Comment: I know how they work I have other delegate methods that call on their own

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85482/discussion-between-coding22-and-mihir-mehta).